# drawRect method get called but the UIView cannot display

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, core-graphics

ModeButtonView is a subclass of UIView, and is already added as a subview of viewController.view:

```
@interface ModeButtonView ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) MonthModeButtonView *monthModeButton;
@end

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (!self) {
        return nil;
     }

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.192 green:0.663      blue:0.647 alpha:1];
    self.monthModeButton = [[MonthModeButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5 * self.bounds.size.width, 0.5 * self.bounds.size.height)];
    self.monthModeButton.center = self.center;
    [self addSubview:self.monthModeButton];
    return self;
}
```

The MonthModeButtonView is also a subclass of UIView, and it is added as a subview of ModeButtonView. Its drawRect method is as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawRect get called");
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.size.height);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextAddPath(currentContext, path);
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathStroke);

    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

I run the program, the ModeButtonView is displayed well on the screen, and the drawRect method of MonthModeButtonView also get called, however, it cannot be displayed on the screen, while I have added it as a subview of ModeButtonView.

However, if I put the code of MonthModeButtonView's drawRect method into ModeButtonView's drawRect method directly, it get displayed. It seems the problem happens because MonthModeButtonView is a subview of MoodeButtonView, but why? Any idea about that?

Comment: Do you really need draw rect, do you just want a border? Are you calling drawRect yourself? Are you setting needs display?

Comment: Hi, Wain, Thanks for reply. I have found the problem of my program, which is the code: self.monthModeButton.center = self.center, because center is the coordinate in the superview's system, since monthModeButton is self's subview, these two centers have two totally different coordinate system, and it makes monthModeButton to be already out of bound. I have deleted this code and it works well now.